# How can I do login with google adsense in an iphone app?

Tags: iphone, authentication

How can I do login with google adsense in an iphone app?
Someone can show me the code? or tell me something about? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2009/06/adsense-for-mobile-applications-beta.html

http://www.google.com/mobileads/publisher_home.html

http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/ios/

Comment: I don't want show adsvon my device...i want loginnin my Google account to' retrive some information like clicks or money earned.... Writing an iPhone app to do it